# Why does my 4D Database debugger not display all panels?

Tags: 4d-database

We are using 4D Server v13. As I connect to the server and run a method with a Trace or breakpoint, I get the debugger with the expression panel missing. The database has been converted from version 6.7.1.

Answer (score 2):

I found this on a 4D Tech discussion. Use the command:

```
SHOW ON DISK(Get 4D folder+"4D Preferences v13.4DPreferences")
```

That will display the preferences file.
Proceed to delete the file and viola,
the debugger behaves back to normal

Answer (score 2):

There are also horizontal lines in the debugger and it's easy to hide them.
Look at my screenshot. All of the vertical and horizontal lines (red circles) can be moved.
Don´t forget to save the debugger settings (green circle) to make changes permanent.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> with the expression panel missing

Left or right ? Maybe try to move this line like :

[image]

If this is not it, try to rename the folder (before close your server 4D) :

```
C:\Documents and Settings\(username)\Application Data\4D Server
```

to

```
C:\Documents and Settings\(username)\Application Data\4D Server_old
```

Launch your server 4D and verify if it's works.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. The right panel does not show up at all. I see a blank area in its space. Even if I drag the line to the left, I still get a blank area. I've changed the folder name as suggested but still see the same blank area. I'm finding it frustrating not to be able to debug.

Comment: If you try to drag the line to the bottom ?

Answer (score 0):

We've moved our OS from Win XP to Win 7. After reinstalling 4D, the debugger behaved normally. I'm still not sure how this is connected, though.

Answer (score 0):

The debugger is limited or doesn't show at all if you try to view it in compiled mode.

http://doc.4d.com/4Dv13/4D/13/Tracing-and-debugging.200-807832.en.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a currently supported version of 4D (v14 or higher), the dimensions of various windows/dialogs are stored within a JSON file found in the [window bounds folder](http://kb.4d.com/assetid=77026) like the following:

Windows:

```
C:\Users\<userName>\AppData\Roaming\4D\<databaseName>\4D Window Bounds v14
```

Mac:

```
/Users/<userName>/Library/Application Support/4D/<databaseName>/4D Window Bounds v14
```

Within these folders are json files that hold the metrics for all of the dialogs including the debugger.

[image]

You can easily delete the JSON file specific to the ***debugger*** and let 4D recreate it with the default values by issuing the following [code](http://kb.4d.com/assetid=77534):

```
C_TEXT($tPath)
$tPath:=Get 4D folder(Active 4D Folder)+"4D Window Bounds v"+Substring(Application version;1;2)+Folder separator+"coreDialog"+Folder separator+"[projectForm]"+Folder separator+"4ddebugger.json"
If (Test path name($tPath)=Is a document)
   DELETE DOCUMENT($tPath)
End if
```

Note: the code above works in all of the currently supported versions of 4D (v14, v15, v15Rx).